# how to output a collection of data from mongodb sort by date

Tags: php, mongodb

I want to retrieve 10 rows of latest news from mongodb. 
First I need to sort the data by the field 'timestamp' by ascending order. Then I need to choose the top 10 rows which are the rows with the latest timestamp. 
This is how I establish my connection (successfully)

```
  $m = new MongoClient("mongodb://127.0.0.1");
  $db = $m ->nutch;
  //echo "Database nutch selected";

  $collection = $db -> crawl_data; 

  $cursor = $collection->find();
```

This is how I tried to get the data following the PHP manual guide

```
  $cursor->sort(array('timestamp' => 1));
  foreach($cursor as $doc){
  echo $doc["title"];
  }
```

FYI: the data type of timestamp is string: "2015/01/31". I am not sure if this is the reason.

Also,  When I do php with MySql, the browser always tells me at which line the problem is. With mongodb, it does not give you any error reporting except a blank page....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The php syntax is a bit confusing.

The `Sort()` and `Limit()` methods can be done on the `find` (regardless of order the sort will always happen first).

It would look something like this:

```
$cursor = $collection->find ()->sort(array('timestamp'=>-1))->limit(10);
```

And then you can reverse the order of the 10 documents in php, or you would probably need to use the aggregation framework.

Comment: thank you! so 'timestamp'=>-1 means the latest date and 'timestamp' =>1 means the oldest date?

Comment: Yes, 1 is ascending and -1 is descending.

Comment: I get error: Call to a member function sort() on array

Answer (score 21):

Sort doesn't work like this anymore, 
To be able to sort with find, you simply use the second find parameter like this:

```
$filter  = [];
$options = ['sort' => ['timestamp' => -1]];

$client = new MongoDB\Client('mongodb://localhost');
$client->mydb->mycollection->find($filter, $options);
```

copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35157963/3713817)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the _id field to sort by timestamp.

The following query can print the latest 10 records.

```
$cursor = $collection->find()->sort( array("_id" => -1 ))->limit(10);
```

Comment: Why not timestamp if it is simple integer in Mongodb?