# How does sorting work in the new mongodb PECL extension?

Tags: php, mongodb

I have just shifted from the old Mongo extension to the newest PHP driver (mongodb). I'm also using the PHP library provided for mongodb.

Previously, I could simply do `->sort()` on a cursor instance, but that doesn't seem to be the case any more since I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method MongoDB\Driver\Cursor::sort()
```

What is the alternative to sorting/limiting/skipping now?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I got an answer about this on the respective [Github repository](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver).

To be able to sort with `find`, you <strike>simply</strike> use the second `find` parameter like this:

```
$filter  = [];
$options = ['sort' => ['username' => 1]];

$client = new MongoDB\Client('mongodb://localhost');
$client->mydb->mycollection->find($filter, $options);
```

For more information, look into the issue I have posted at the repository:

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/issues/214

Comment: @ErwinWessels: respected your request.

Comment: Thanks @aborted - can't deny a bit of frustration creeping into my comment there re. the lack of functionality on this new cursor implementation -- since we were passing these around, we had to change quite a lot of functionality....