# sorting is not possible in MongoDB PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb

I am using the official [mongo php library](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-php-library/) and when i try to use the [cursors.sort()](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/) method it returns this error:

> Call to undefined method MongoDB\Driver\Cursor::sort()

Here is my code object:

```
public function recent_posts()
{
    $uid = $this->user_id;
    $posts= $this->db->$uid; 
    return $posts
        ->find(
            [ '_id' => [ '$not' => [ '$eq' => '5' ] ] ]
        )->sort( [ '$natural' => -1 ] );
}
```

How sort would work here?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35147845/how-does-sorting-work-in-the-new-mongodb-pecl-extension